# Upgrading from Groovy 1.7.2 to 1.8.x

Tags: groovy

My project demands and upgrade from groovy 1.7.2 to 1.8.x stable release, there are several jar's are created using groovy 1.7.2 version, let me know whether these jar's will be compatible with 1.8.x also or not, or do i need to completely re-built it,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it says on [this mailing list entry](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Jar-compatibility-between-1-7-and-1-8-td4476000.html):

> A jar built with 1.7 will not run with a 1.8 runtime because two files were moved and one was removed.

Comment: thnaks, i don't have to change my source code in this regard Is the compatibility issue only with direct use of RegexExpression, Value, and ValueRecorder? Or are there other indirect dependencies?

Comment: You should just have to recompile unless you directly use these classes

Comment: Thanks, my software is a server side application which build on groovy 1.7, and the customer can use this software to upload their application by converting their application using groovy 1.7, and we don't have directly control on their jar , the product demands groovy 1.8.x upgrade, at the same time we have support backward compatibility  for 1.7 can u help me how this can be performed, or we have to advise customer also to upgrade the jar also ?